# Better term for "iOS Camera Roll"?

Tags: ios, terminology

We are using the term "iOS Camera Roll" for our iOS App to indicate that we refer to all the pictures and videos the user has on their *iDevice*.

Since I'm not a native English speaker the term "Camera Roll" seemed a little bit confusing to me. I was also wondering if the younger generation (that maybe never used an analog camera) would understand what we are referring to.

What is the modern way to refer to the user's media content on their iDevice?

Comment: Does your 'Camera roll' show exactly the same things as if one goes on the iDevice to Photos > Camera roll?

Comment: @Izhaki, not sure. On my (German) localized version of iOS 8 it does not use the term "Canrea Roll" or similar. I was confused by this differentiation all the time. I'm looking to find a description of ALL of those contents. How would you describe this (App)? Photos Library? Media Library?

Comment: You could simply go for term "Gallery" or "Camera Roll" itself and no need to add prefix iOS as device itself is iDevice.

Answer (score 2):

*Visual Media* would cover both *pictures* and *films* (or *photos* and *videos*) as it is a collective term for both. However, it is a little formal. Or have a separate table for photos and videos and don't group them together in one *camera roll*.

You may be better off just sticking to the term *camera roll* as even if the younger generation have never seen an actual camera roll, they will be used to the term from having used their iPhones/iPads etc. anyway. Better to stick with an already excepted term, than introducing a new term for something that already exists. As they say, consistancy in the UI and UX reigns supreme.

Answer (score 0):

## *Your Photos* or *Photos*

Apple itself refers to the contents of the Photos App as "Photos" or "Your Photos". Those screen shots show how Apple asks for permissions to access the contents of the Photos App.

[image: your photos ios permission]

[image: photos ios permission]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard, but you could refer to **"Camera gallery"**, which would be a more common term for anything that has visual content, both on and off-line.

If you want a more technical term even **"Camera folder"** could work.

If you want to make sure the user understands it's on the device they're holding, you could preface it with "My" (or "your", depending on the sentence structure). This insinuates it's theirs, and in combination with the word "camera" it pretty specifically refers to something they've created with the camera relevant to the context of the device they're holding.

So I'd suggest **"My camera gallery"**, or **"My gallery"** in case it's not exclusive to camera related imagery.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS '**All Photos**' mean both Photos and Videos.

From home screen press

```
Camera > Image Thumb (bottom left corner) > 'All Photos' (top left corner)
```

You will see all your Photos and Videos.

You better stick with the term what iOS is currently using.
 So I would use '**All Photos**'.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **Photos**

*(ref screenshot from Dropbox app for iOS)*

[image]